# svg - embed png image height null

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I would like to embed a png image into svg container but wish to keep aspect ratio, so I only add width property in png element. how can I get the height of the png image in javascript for this case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#img {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="mysvg" viewBox="0 0 800 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <title>SVG demo</title>
  <desc>example SVG</desc>
  <image id="img" xlink:href="input.png" width="500" x="100" y="100" />
</svg>
<script>
// initialize
const
  svg = document.getElementById('mysvg'),
  img = document.getElementById('img');

  img.onload = function() {
    console.log("x:",img.getAttribute('x'));
    console.log("y:",img.getAttribute('y'));
    console.log("width:",img.getAttribute('width'));
    console.log("height:",img.getAttribute('height'));
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This example will output as below:

```
x:100
y:100
width:500
height:null
```

I would like to read out the height value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#content_versus_idl_attributes), `getAttribute` reads content attributes, and you are setting none. You can read the IDL attribute with `window.getComputedStyle`:

```js
// initialize
const
  svg = document.getElementById('mysvg'),
  img = document.getElementById('img');

  img.onload = function() {
    console.log("x:",img.getAttribute('x'));
    console.log("y:",img.getAttribute('y'));
    console.log("width:",img.getAttribute('width'));
    console.log("height:",window.getComputedStyle(img).height);
  }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="mysvg" viewBox="0 0 800 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <title>SVG demo</title>
  <desc>example SVG</desc>
  <image id="img" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dwrn.png" width="500" x="100" y="100" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This approach works on Chrome, but not on Firefox.  It also relies on behaviour defined in the draft SVG2 spec. It is possible that some browsers have not yet implemented that behaviour. I haven't checked.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I don't think that you can do that per the specification. i.e. the computed style should return auto, not a value and as far as I know that's what Firefox does i.e. we've no plans to change it and would likely not accept a bug to "fix" it to what Chrome does.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yeah I did check what the spec says. But I wasn't 100% sure on whether the statement "the percentage or 'auto' or the absolute length" ruled out the browser returning an "absolute length" in this case.  I wasn't trying to claim Firefox was wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Her's an approach that should work in all modern-ish browsers.

```js
let img = document.getElementById('img');
// Wait for SVG <image> element to finish loading
img.onload = function() {
  // Create an HTML <img> element with the same URL so we can get
  // the image's naturalWidth and naturalHeight
  let tmp = new Image();
  tmp.onload = function () {
    // Calculate the final <image> height using the width and
    // the image's natural (actual) width and height
    w = img.width.baseVal.value;
    h = w * tmp.naturalHeight / tmp.naturalWidth;
    console.log('width='+w+' height='+h);
  }
  tmp.src = img.getAttribute('xlink:href');
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <image id="img" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/00_1373_Milford_Sound_-New_Zealand.jpg/640px-00_1373_Milford_Sound_-New_Zealand.jpg" width="500" x="100" y="100" />
</svg>
```